# django drf login template

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I extend the login template of DRF

```
{% extends "rest_framework/login_base.html" %}
{% block branding %}
  <h3 style="margin: 0 0 20px;">My site</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

with urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^login', login, template_name, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout', logout, template_name, name='logout'),
...
```

Everything works well except if the connection fails: DRF redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-auth/login/ instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/ and my extended template is not used. So I lose my site name for "Django REST framework" title.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the template in  `templates/rest_framework/` and

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you extended it on ***project/templates/rest_framework/login.html***:

```
{% extends "rest_framework/login_base.html" %}
{% block branding %}
   <h3 style="margin: 0 0 20px;">My site</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

The name of your project's login form which is 'my site', shouldn't change.

For the unified resource locator you can try this:

```
    url(r'^', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
```

So that upon redirection the url will be like in the below sample:

```
http://localhost:8000/login/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
```